# Переход к предыдущему Activity

Tags: activity, android

Скажите, пожалуйста, как вернуться из Activity D в Activity B? но так чтобы в Activity B не сработало событие onCreate, а отработало onRestart ? Вот так не работает :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("sj.action.vacancyDetail");              
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);             
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Так может, при переходе C->D прибить C?

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы запускаете Activity внутри какого то другого Activity, то в вашем ActivityBackStack поверх старого Activity накладывается новый Activity, а ваш старый Activity уходит в режим Background методом (onStop()) для того, чтобы из нового Activity вам вернуться обратно в предыдущее Activity, вам необходимо вызвать в новом Activity метод finish(), и в Таком случай ваш новое Activity уничтожится из ActivityBackStack методом (onDestroy()) а ваше старое Activity вернется обратно из режима Background в режим Foreground методом (onResume()) и причем метод (onCreate()) вызван не будет.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, неправильно полагаться на Activity Lifecycle с целью использовать методы инициализации для какого-то действия.

Может случиться так, что Activity B уже разрушено, чтобы освободить память. В таком сценарии метод onCreate() будет вызван обязательно.

Но если Вы уверены, что Activity B не разрушено, попробуйте использовать `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Comment: ну FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT не совсем правильно, попав с таким флагом в Activity B и нажав кнопку назад я не смогу попасть в Activity A. А хотелось бы сохранить последовательность окон.

Comment: >> Так может, при переходе C->D прибить C?

пробовали?

Comment: Неплохая идея. Попробую. Ну а всё таки, почему с флагом FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK для Activity B запускается событие onCreate, а не onRestart (я смотрел - в Activity B при уходе с неё отрабатывает onStop(), onDestroy() не запускается). А вообще я вот подумал насчёт вашей мысли ("Может случиться так, что Activity B уже разрушено, чтобы освободить память.") - может и в правду в onCreate() при помощи Bundle savedInstanceState восстановить первоначальное состояние Activity B.